# Does GNOME Files (Nautilus) support copy queue in sequential mode?

Tags: nautilus, copy-and-paste

When dragging/dropping files one by one from one GNOME Files (Nautilus) window to another they will be copied in parallel. This leads to a large and not needed workload without speeding up the transfer of any single file.

Does anyone know how to force GNOME Files to use the file copy queue in sequential mode (one file after another)?

To make my question more precise: I do not ask how to queue sequentially with the help of another program. I expect GNOME Files to be able to handle sequential mode, but simply don't know how to activate it.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, the old answers to similar questions are still valid. Nautilus does not provide such mechanism.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that Gnome Files (Nautilus) is not able to queue sequentially? Do you have a proof of that? A manual page or feature list from the gnome site for example? Or are you only guessing?